# object text to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

Trying to display pdfs with some reusable code across several pages.

I have this:

```
<a href="http://somesite.com/someplace">click me</a>
```

So that that google pdf viewer works, I have to encode the html. So, I grab the href and encode it like so:

```
var bar = this.href, // == http://somesite.com/someplace
    foo = bar.replace(/:/g, "%3A").replace(/\//g, "%2F");
```

Then I try to stick that value into an element later like so:

```
myElement.src = 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + foo + '&embedded=true';
```

It doesn't work since foo is a text object. When I hardcode it in it works great, but I don't want to hardcode it in for every page on the site. 
When I log it to the console I get this:

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[object%20Text]&embedded=true
```

How to I get around this? Do I have to convert foo to a string? How do I do that?

Comment: Looks okay here: http://jsfiddle.net/xg6at/

Comment: Need more info, what does `this` point to? I don't think it's the link DOM node. Also, you don't need use `replace`, you should be using `encodeURIComponent(bar)` instead as it is built for exactly this purpose.

Comment: there is an onlick event listener involved and the this keyword points to the a tag.

Comment: I used encodeURIComponent() and instead and now it works... I don't get it, but I'm happy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`myElement.src = 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + foo.nodeValue + '&embedded=true';`